# Not able to remove object from supabase storage

Tags: supabase

I'm using supabase client.

```
const { data, error }  = await supabase.storage
    .from('main')
    .remove([input.imageId])
```

imageId is the correct path. When I test it with getting the object like this:

```
const { data: fileExistsData } = supabase.storage
            .from('main')
            .getPublicUrl(input.imageId);
```

I get the object successfully, but when I try to remove it the error and data look like this:

```
Error:  null
Data:  []
```

I tried to have my objects in the folder as well to see if it would help but same issue persists. I do have a basic DELETE permission set: `(bucket_id = 'main'::text)`
And also for storage.objects using expression `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `select` policy as well as the `delete` policy in order to delete the files in your bucket even if your bucket is a public bucket.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Thanks a lot!